# How to correctly share a command line argument among multiple classes that initialize each other in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, parameter-passing

My project structure is the following

```
|-- project/
   |-- run.py
   |-- classes/
      |-- module_defining_class_a.py [=> class classA():...]
      |-- module_defining_class_b.py [=> class classB():...]
   |-- config.yaml
```

where `run.py` initializes a `ClassA` object, which in turn initializes a `ClassB` object.

Now `run.py` also parses a command line argument pointing to a `config.yaml` file. The dictionary that results from parsing this `.yaml` file contains keys and values that are required by both `ClassA` and `ClassB` when they are initialized.

My question is: How can I best share this command line argument across both classes?

The obvious solution would be to pass it to the `__init__` method of `ClassA` and have it pass the `config` dictionary on to the `__init__` method of `ClassB`; but this feels unelegant because the argument would then be passed down in a waterfall-like manner. I would much rather be able to access the command line argument from within each class when instantiating it, without passing it to the `__init__` method repeatedly as an argument.

Am I correct in assuming that passing the argument down via multiple levels is not good design? If so, what could be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my opinion it is an acceptable, and relatively elegant way (if you are passing down to ClassB only the relevant part of the data).

I can think of a few other ways:

- Have a common settings class, which is initialized first in run.py, and both ClassA and ClassB are getting their settings from it. - In this case ClassA and ClassB need a reference to this class - does not differ much from your solution. You would be passing down a class, instead of a dictionary.
- Have a class or function, which reads in the data from the config file as needed. You could even have a base class implement this functionality, and make ClassA and ClassB inherit from it. It could work as a kind of "Deserializable" interface. ([There are no interfaces in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124190/how-do-i-implement-interfaces-in-python))
- You could have your run.py initialize ClassA and ClassB, and inject the ClassB reference to ClassA (either constructor or property).
- You could use [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function), but that is not elegant, and dangerous.