# Design pattern recommendations for oop game

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Hi, I'm making a simple oop game in python using pygame.

Currently, my game object classes have methods like move, draw and check collision. I would like to create a new class with the intention of handling these interactions in a way that my game object classes don't have to know about other game objects anymore

Here are the abstract classes for the game objects

```
import pygame
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import copy


class ABCObject(ABC):
def __init__(self, initial_x: int, initial_y: int, size: int, color: tuple):
    self._size = size
    self._rect = pygame.Rect(
        initial_x, initial_y, self._size, self._size)
    self._color = color

@property
def size(self):
    return self._size

@property
def rect(self):
    return self._rect

@property
def color(self):
    return self._color

@size.setter
def size(self, new_size: int):
    if isinstance(new_size, int):
        self._size = new_size

@color.setter
def color(self, new_color: tuple):
    if isinstance(new_color, tuple):
        if len(new_color) == 3 and isinstance(new_color[1], int) and isinstance(new_color[0], int) and isinstance(new_color[2], int):
            self._color = new_color

def draw(self, win, offset):
    fake_rect = copy.deepcopy(self._rect)
    fake_rect.topleft -= offset
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self._color, fake_rect)
```

```
from abc_object import ABCObject


class Kinetic_object(ABCObject, ABC):
    def __init__(self, initial_x: int, initial_y: int, size: int, color: tuple, speed: int):
        super().__init__(initial_x, initial_y, size, color)
        self._speed = speed
        self._velX = 0
        self._velY = 0

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

    @property
    def velX(self):
        return self._velX

    @property
    def velY(self):
        return self._velY

    @velX.setter
    def velX(self, new_velX):
        if isinstance(new_velX, (int, float)):
            self._velX = new_velX

    @velY.setter
    def velY(self, new_velY):
        if isinstance(new_velY, (int, float)):
            self._velY = new_velY

    @speed.setter
    def speed(self, new_speed):
        if isinstance(new_speed, int):
            self._speed = new_speed

    @abstractmethod
    def move(self):
        pass
```

And here is my player class:

```
import math
import copy
from abc_command import Command
from abc_kinetic_object import Kinetic_object


class Player(Kinetic_object, Command):
    def __init__(self, initial_x: int, initial_y: int, size: int, speed: int, obstacles: list):
        Kinetic_object.__init__(
            self, initial_x, initial_y, size, (250, 160, 60),  speed)
        Command.__init__(
            self, {'up': False, 'down': False, 'right': False, 'left': False})
        # usar depois para mudar sprite
        self._facing_direction = 'down'
        self._obstacles = obstacles

    # usar para normalizar os vetores de velocidade, caso contrario, anda mais rápido nas diagonais
    def normalize(self):
        if self._velX != 0 and self._velY != 0:
            self._velX *= 1/math.sqrt(2)
            self._velY *= 1/math.sqrt(2)


    # Colisoes, funciona se nao colidir com objetos em movimento
    def move(self):
        self.normalize()
        self._rect.x += self._velX
        self.check_collisions('horizontal')
        self._rect.y += self._velY
        self.check_collisions('vertical')

    def check_collisions(self, direction):
        if direction == 'horizontal':
            for obstacle in self._obstacles:
                if obstacle.rect.colliderect(self._rect):
                    if self._velX > 0:  # direita
                        self._rect.right = obstacle.rect.left
                    elif self._velX < 0:  # esquerda
                        self._rect.left = obstacle.rect.right

        if direction == 'vertical':
            for obstacle in self._obstacles:
                if obstacle.rect.colliderect(self._rect):
                    if self._velY > 0:  # baixo
                        self._rect.bottom = obstacle.rect.top
                    elif self._velY < 0:  # cima
                        self._rect.top = obstacle.rect.bottom

    def change_facing_direction(self):
        # so apertando para direita
        if self._commands['right'] and not (self._commands['down'] or self._commands['up'] or self._commands['left']):
            self._facing_direction = 'right'
        # so apertando para esquerda
        elif self._commands['left'] and not (self._commands['down'] or self._commands['up'] or self._commands['right']):
            self._facing_direction = 'left'
        # so apertando para cima
        elif self._commands['up'] and not (self._commands['down'] or self._commands['right'] or self._commands['left']):
            self._facing_direction = 'up'
        # so apertando para baixo
        elif self._commands['down'] and not (self._commands['up'] or self._commands['left'] or self._commands['right']):
            self._facing_direction = 'down'

    def execute_commands(self):
        self.change_facing_direction()
        self._velX = 0
        self._velY = 0
        if self._commands['left'] and not self._commands['right']:
            self._velX = -self._speed
        if self._commands['right'] and not self._commands['left']:
            self._velX = self._speed
        if self._commands['up'] and not self._commands['down']:
            self._velY = -self._speed
        if self._commands['down'] and not self._commands['up']:
            self._velY = self._speed
```

I would like to know which design pattern would be appropriate in order to remove methods like "move" from game objects and implement them in other controller classes, I have different objects that all move in a different way.

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if you got rid of all the superfluous properties. For example, drop `velX` and work directly with your attributes. If someone tries to add something that *isn't* a number to such an attribute, that's a bug to fix, not something to ignore.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Python, however I would like to share with my thoughts via C# and in addition I will attach link about [how to convert interface to abstract class of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124190/how-do-i-implement-interfaces-in-python).

I do not think that there is a pattern which says where we should put `move()` method. However, we can create an interface `IMoveable` and implement it in desired classes.

```
public interface IMoveable
{
    void Move();
}
```

And classes where we can implement this interface:

```
public class Player : IMoveable
{
    public void Move() { }
}   


class Kinetic_object : IMoveable
{
    public void Move() { }
}
```

It is possible to use inheritance here. However, by using inheritance [we can easily violate of Liskov substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

For example we can create base class and call it `Unit` and declare method `Move`:

```
public abstract class Unit
{
    public abstract void Move();
}
```

And then just use it in out classes:

```
public class Player : Unit
{
    public void Move()
    {
        
    }
}
```

However, if game will have turret, then by doing this we violates Liskov substitution principle:

```
public class Turret : Unit
{
    public void Move()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // violation of Liskov substitution principle
    }
}
```

So, [we prefered composition over inheritance here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)